# What is wrong with this plant?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

[image: What is wrong with this plant?]

It has been like that for quite a while it looks like something upset her. What is wrong with it?

Comment: What sort of light is available to the plant? Has the light changed recently, e.g plant moved, different bulb, room painted resulting in less reflected light etc? How large is the pot - maybe it's time to repot? Have there been changes to air quality or room temperature. How old is the plant etc. Please tell us about the plant's environment and history.

Comment: same light, nothing has changed. You can see that with the same light the plant was OK previously.

Answer (score 2):

This plant is called Dracaena marginata or the dragon tree. It can be distinguished by it's yellow roots.  [Here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_marginata) are some pictures of these plants when grown in high light.

The appearance of your plant is consistent with a plant grown in low light. When this happens leaves fall towards the stem.

You should also check the undersides of the leaves for spider mites. They look like little grains of salt. They will cause leaf drop, usually from the bottom up.

You can perk the plant up by providing more light, either artificial or natural.

Comment: Thanks kevisnsky! The plant does not seem to have parasites, I believe it is the light I will try to move it to a brighter spot. Can it be the water ?

Comment: @user2059078 - what is your watering regime? How long has the plant been in the same pot? Have you had your heating up high during the last few weeks/months?

Comment: Can't say much about watering; my wife waters this from time to time, not regularly but the water is provided when the soil is dry. Yes heating went up in the building due to very low temperatures in Canada. The plant has been in the same pot for around 2 years I have another one which is in the same shape, just in another room... just a little less unhappy than this one