# How can I save this plant sprout?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, optimal-conditions

In my other question [What is this plant on the pictures?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/28764/what-is-this-plant-on-the-pictures) I was asking about the identity of certain plant.
The reason I was asking was that this plant has gone for the worse recently.
The whole plant somehow faded and the liitle sprout seen on first picture has sagged and lost most of its leaves. Well, it went from bad to worse. The liitle sprout just toppled over with no roots left. My guess is that the roots have rotted away. My question is: Can I save that sprout and how. Would putting it in a water with a bit of liquid fertiliser help? Or is it gone.
My worry is that the big plant might follow soon.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like it has a couple roots. I would personally just try putting it in water for a couple days (no fertilizer) and then plant it in soil (and give it a bit of extra potassium when you do, without extra nitrogen, unless your soil is high in potassium already). I don't know if it'll survive, but lacking knowledge about the plant, that's what I would want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is root rot due to over watering and insufficient light.  Very common with these plants as indicated in my answer to your previous question.

There is the possibility of spider mites. Examine the underside of the leaves with a magnifying glass for what appears to be grains of salt.  If present wipe the leaves, top and bottom, with a solution of 5 ml dish soap to 1 liter of water. Repeat three times at five to seven day intervals.

Do not put the cutting in water.  Use a rooting hormone if available and pot up in a medium that keeps the roots moist, not wet.  You can use peat, coconut coir, perlite or sphagnum moss.  Be sure to put this in a high light area.  High humidity with air movement helps.

Comment: On 27th reading of your answer I must point out that you correctly guessed the culprit conditions. The plant was over watered and put in a dark place for a week. There was even a freshly grown mushroom. And I really liked that plant with it's afro haircut.